# Remove h1 text from column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my wordpress database, I have several references in my posts fields such as:

```
<h1>title text</h1>  ... blah blah rest of post
```

I want to remove all the h1 tags (and text within h1 tags) from hundreds of entries.  Is there a query that will accomplish that?

Comment: Some details on the table column names would be needed to write a query for this purpose.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be multiple H1 tags in an entry?

Comment: There is only one h1 tag per post.  The column is post_content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below query will remove all H1 entries from the post_content column of your table. The statement concats the left side of the H1 content with the right side of the H1 content.

```
UPDATE table
SET post_content = CONCAT(SUBSTR(post_content, 1, LOCATE('<h1>', post_content) - 1),
    SUBSTR(post_content, LOCATE('</h1>', post_content) + 5));
```